# While inserting, replace NULL with previous non-null value

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have a Postgres table with columns like this:

```
(id, foreign_key, big_int, value_1, value_2)
```

`id` is the autoincrement primary key, there is a unique key on `foreign_key` and `big_int` columns. I am inserting several million records into this table using several large `INSERT .. VALUES (),()...()` calls.

One of `value_1` or `value_2` is usually `NULL`, both can be set, too, but both are never `NULL`.
What I wish to achieve is to eliminate `NULL` besides the initial `NULLs` by replacing the `NULL` in the `INSERT` with the previous non-null values for `value_1` and `value_2` **among all rows for foreign_key where big_int is max** (due to the unique index there will only be one row and this should also be the row inserted before the one to be inserted - if it makes things easier).

How can I do that in a *fast* way? I stumbled upon the `LAG()` function, but I didn't figure out how to use it properly.

Example:

Lets assume I am inserting the following values:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (foreign_key, big_int, value_1, value_2) VALUES
(1, 5000, NULL, 50  ),
(1, 5001, 51,   NULL),
(2, 6000, 20,   NULL),
(1, 5002, NULL, 52  ),
(2, 6001, 21,   22  ),
(1, 5003, 53,   54  );
```

Then the resulting table is supposed to look like this (omitting the id column):

```
1 | 5000 | NULL | 50    -> inserted as is since there is no previous row for foreign_key 1
1 | 5001 | 51   | 50    -> 50 for value_2 column copied from previous row for foreign_key 1
2 | 6000 | 20   | NULL  -> inserted as is since there is no previous row for foreign_key 2
1 | 5002 | 51   | 52    -> 51 for value_1 column copied from previous row for foreign_key 1
2 | 6001 | 21   | 22    -> 22 for value_2 column copied from previous row for foreign_key 2
1 | 5003 | 53   | 54    -> no need to copy since both values have been provided
```

I am sure I have to modify the INSERT statement. Anything else (triggers?, etc) seem to slow.

Comment: A table of sample data is worth a thousand words for SO SQL questions.  That being said, can you include some sample data?

Comment: I can, after lunch!

Comment: Well, hopefully I've you some food for thought `:-)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There you go!

Comment: I think that you should use some algorithm for to store data before inserting

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE for the `VALUES` to make use of the `lag` window function in the `INSERT`:

```
WITH input(foreign_key, big_int, value_1, value_2) AS (VALUES
  (…),
  …)
INSERT INTO my_table (foreign_key, big_int, value_1, value_2)
SELECT
  foreign_key,
  big_int,
  COALESCE(value_1, lag(value_1) OVER (ORDER BY big_int)),
  COALESCE(value_2, lag(value_2) OVER (ORDER BY big_int))
FROM input;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=251cc096638b3d02849c80de4dd59d06))</sup>

Comment: This would work with one INSERT, right? But if I have several INSERTs, the `SELECT ... FROM input` would only work on the current set of VALUES, wouldn't it? Could I do something like `SELECT ... FROM input UNION SELECT (..same columns..) FROM my_table`?

Comment: Should be `UNION ALL`

Comment: But with such a large UNION ALL table I wouldn't have indexes and the functions used in the SELECT would take forever. Is this correct?

Comment: Oh you mean you want to take the current max values from the table? I guess you can do that by using `COALESCE(value_1, lag…, (SELECT value_1 FROM my_table WHERE value_1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY big_int DESC LIMIT 1))`, which should use the existing index on `big_int` to get the find last non-null `value_1`.

Comment: Thank you! However this did not work. Also, any CTE I've tried would be too slow unfortunately. I therefore created a second table which stores the max(big_int) values by foreign_key. I load this small table into memory and create my INSERTs with direct values from that table in memory. The content is updated with every new max for big_int and written back to DB asynchronously every few seconds.